# What legal document is the reference for periods of residency needed for obtaining Spanish citizenship?

Tags: citizenship, spain, naturalization

I've read on a [government website](https://administracion.gob.es/pag_Home/en/Tu-espacio-europeo/derechos-obligaciones/ciudadanos/residencia/obtencion-nacionalidad.html#-f9cef8f9cd4e) about periods of residency required for obtaining the citizenship of Spain. I would like to consult the legal reference for the described periods of one, two, five, and ten years respectively. I haven´t found anything about those periods in [Ley Orgánica 4/2000, de 11 de enero, sobre derechos y libertades de los extranjeros en España y su integración social](https://www.boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-2000-544). In what legal document might I read about such periods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The government website itself sets out the legal basis at the bottom, specifically, the [Civil Code](https://www.boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-1889-4763) and the Royal Decree 1004/2015 of 6 November approving the Regulation governing the procedure for acquiring Spanish nationality by residency.

The citizenship provisions are set out in Book 1 (Persons) Title 1 (Spaniards and aliens) of the Civil Code.

The acquisition by residence is regulated by Article 22, which states in part

> 1. Granting of citizenship pursuant to residence shall require ten years’ residence. Five
>    years shall be sufficient for persons who have obtained asylum or refugees, and two
>    years for citizens by birth right of Ibero-American countries, Andorra, the Philippines,
>    Equatorial Guinea or Portugal, or for Sephardic Jews. [...]